# Proving 1 = 2 by POAC( Principle of Atom Conservation )

Tags: physical-chemistry, mole

I have been told that applying POAC in any equation means conserving the number of moles of an element in both reactant and product . 
For example : 
$$\ce{H2 + O2 -> H2O}$$ 
Here when we apply POAC on oxygen we write :

Equation 1 :

No. Of Atoms(or moles) of "O" in reactant =  No. Of Atoms(or moles ) of "O" in product

Equation 2: (obtained from equation 1)

2(moles of $\ce{O2}$) = 1(moles of $\ce{H2O}$)

Where equation 2 gives us the necessary data required in solving questions of stoichiometric calculations .
I understand how equation 2 comes from equation 1 **but I don't understand why equation 1 is correct even when the chemical equation is unbalanced** ?

*As I think* equation 1 can be applied only when the chemical equation is balanced . 
As here :

No. Of Atoms of "O" in reactant =2

No of Atoms of "O" in product = 1

Thus by equation 1 we can say that  $1=2$ .

And **my book says POAC can be applied even when equation is not balanced** . So here equation is not balanced and when I apply POAC I get $1=2$ . **So what's is wrong with my reasoning**?

Comment: Atoms cannot be created or destroyed in a chemical reaction, hence we must balance equations for all the types of atoms involved, i.e. there have to be the same number of each type on either side. In your example $\ce{2H2 +  O2 = 2H2O}$

Comment: If I am interpreting your question correctly, equation 1 is basically a demand that you balance your equation. So:

$$ H_2 + O_2 = H_2O $$

is not balanced, therefore equation 1 doesn't really apply. I would say that "equation 1" is not even really an equation, more of a demand, or statement that must be fulfilled.

Comment: @porphyrin I know my chemical equation is not correct and must be balanced but the point I want to make is while applying POAC we don't need to balance the equation(so says my book ) !! So that is why while writing equation 1,2(applying POAC ) I have not balanced the chemical equation

Comment: @iammax If equation 1 is incorrect ( which I too think it is ) then equation 2 is also incorrect but that is what my book , teacher has been applying as POAC  in questions were balancing the chemical equation is difficult (to use mole-mole analysis ) by trial and error

Comment: @Freelancer Well, without having seen the exact wording in the book, I would say that it is quite wrong to declare that you don't need to balance the equation to apply POAC. In fact, I don't think you CAN apply POAC to an unbalanced reaction; conserving the number of moles is equivalent to saying the reaction is balanced, as the number of moles on each side is conserved by going to the other side of the reaction. If it's unbalanced, it leads to a contradiction, as you have noticed (the 1 = 2 contradiction). So I think perhaps the book is wrong, or you are misinterpreting what the book says.

Comment: @iammax what about this answer here , I think it is saying the same thing as I said about applying POAC in unbalanced reactions  https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-principle-of-atom-conservation-explain-with-an-example

Comment: @Freelancer In your linked question, their reaction is unbalanced, but they essentially balance it in the calculations. Note the line:

$$ \mathrm{Moles\ of\ } O_2 = \frac{3}{2} x \mathrm{Moles\ }  KClO_3 $$

This step is to account for the fact that the reaction is unbalanced, but in your example in the first post where you "prove" 2 = 1, you don't include a step like this, which is why you are getting a contradiction.

Comment: @iammax I think I have understood what you are trying to say, I have written a answer here , *based on what I have understood* . is it correct and according to the facts ( as I don't want to post anything which is wrong )  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by many others ,  The equation 1 given above is simply put **very wrong**  . As it can be applied *only when a balanced chemical equation is given to us* ,  otherwise we will reach at all sorts of contradictions as in the question above .

However many non- rigorous teachers , textbooks often write equation 1 in POAC (which is always true in a balanced chemical equation ) and then say now equation 2 is obtained from equation 1(which is partially incorrect) . It is true equation 2 comes naturally from equation 1 , *but only for a balanced chemical equation*.

**So then how come we apply equation 2 in POAC in all sorts of question ? And still come up with the right answer ?**

The answer is that *equation 2 is true in itself always* whether the chemical equation given ( in POAC ) is balanced or not . So it is not related to equation  1 for its validity .

**How is equation 2 always valid ?**

As pointed out by @iammax in the comments actually we (sort of )  essentially balanced the chemical equation given to us in the equation 2 itself .

For example in the $KClO_3$ question linked above , the moles of $O_2$ , moles of $KClO_3$ given to us are actually according to the stoichiometric coefficients , which **enable** us to use POAC without balancing the reaction (even though we have done that indirectly by using No. of moles of $O_2$ , $KClO_3$).

---

To conclude we can say after using No. Of moles of reactant , product we have indirectly balanced the chemical equation as the Ratio of their number of moles will be 
Equal  to Ratio of their respective stoichiometric coefficients . After which we just use Conservation of Atoms( as the name says it) and multiply the number of moles of the molecule with the number of Atoms present  on which POAC is being applied ( For example we multiply no. Of moles of $O_2$ by 2 when we apply POAC on oxygen atom ).

Answer (score 1):

The reaction you have written $\ce{H2 + O2 -> H2O}$ simply reads hydrogen and oxygen react to form water. It is a way to write incomplete information and it isn't quite correct. Do note that reactions *must* always be balanced for accuracy.

Principle of atom conservation (POAC) states that in a given chemical reaction (where no nuclear reactions are observed) the number of atoms of all elements remain constant. POAC is really a *practical* principle based on the fact that (in a chemical reaction where no nuclear reactions are observed) **atoms can neither appear out of nowhere nor disappear into thin ai**r. If you were to do an experiment and calculate the number of atoms of hydrogen and oxygen present in the reaction mixture before and after the reaction, it would be equal. POAC may even be applied to complex reactions where there is no need to balance the reaction in order to find the amount of product formed because it may be calculated by equaling number of atoms. Really, it just avoids a few cumbersome steps while solving questions.

You may be misinterpreting POAC. I think a more accurate way to state POAC would be '***observed* number of atoms of all elements in a reaction mixture before and after a chemical reaction (where no nuclear reaction is occurring) are equal.**' Do note the emphasis '*observed*.'